# How to know which product(s) to initialize with?

Tags: plaid

Any best practices for handling a situation where you have called link/token/create with a certain product (investments, for example) but the end-user only has accounts that are supported by a different product and therefore gets an error message?

An example would be when the user tries to connect to the institution Navient - Loans (which supports assets, balance, transactions, signal, income, identity, investments, liabilities). We typically will initialize with investments as that is core to our use case, but if the user only has student loans with Navient, they will get an error (NO_INVESTMENT_ACCOUNTS).

I suppose one solution would be to ask the user what type of account(s) they want to connect prior to calling link/token/create so that we can initialize with the correct product, but it seems so clunky for the user.

Answer (score 0):

There's some documentation on the topic here: https://plaid.com/docs/link/initializing-products/

The correct answer to this depends on your use case, but from your question, it sounds like you're doing a wealth management / net worth tracker style account aggregation app. In that case, asking the user for the account type before they link is in fact the recommended practice (although I agree, it is a little clunky).